# Can I display SSRS 2008 reports in a .Net 2 website?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

We have an asp.net 2.0 web forms application that a client hosts on their extranet.  The site displays some reports from a SQL Server 2005 database (and therefore SSRS 2005).  We do this using the ReportViewer control (v9).

The client has just told us that they are migrating the database to a new server which has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed.

We have developed SSRS 2008 reports before, but only for use in .Net 4 websites.  Should we be able to display 2008 reports in a .Net 2 website or are we going to need to upgrade the website to 3.5?

I know that SSRS 2008 is quite a different tool to 2005 but all we want to be able to do is deploy 2005 reports to a 2008 server and, ideally, just change the URL that the website connects to.  Alas I think I am being a bit optimistic!  I have done a lot of searching online but am just getting confused between versions of SSRS, VS, ReportViewer controls etc.  Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes!

We opened the .rptproj (2005) using BIDS 2008, and allowed it to upgrade the project file.  We then opened each report in turn and previewed it (thus the reports were upgraded to 2008).  These were deployed to a 2008 instance of SSRS and we only had to change the connection string in the .net 2 website, nothing else.  For once I wasn't being optimistic!